# Apt search does not search all fields

Tags: apt

Is there a way of including the `Source` and/or `Homepage` fields in apt searches of available (ie *not* installed) packages? For example

```
apt search pyyaml
```

does not produce any results eventhough

```
apt show python3-yaml
```

shows 2 fields `Source` and `Homepage` with the word `pyyaml`. The documented options for search do not help; is there another command or another way of searching?

Answer (score 1):

## Installed packages

You can use `dpkg-query` (see [`man dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) for details) command for this purpose.

We will use the following fields of packages:

- > **`binary:Package`**
  >   It contains the binary package name with a possible architecture qualifier  like  “libc6:amd64”  (since  dpkg  1.16.2).   An
  >   architecture  qualifier  will  be  present to make the package name unambiguous, for example if the package has a Multi-Arch
  >   field with a value of same or the package is of a foreign architecture.
- **`Version`** - package version;
- **`Homepage`** - home page of the project, **the field you requested**;
- > **`source:Package`**
  >    It contains the source package name for this binary package (since dpkg 1.16.2).

The command to list all available packages:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} ${Version}\t${Homepage}\t${source:Package}\n' "*"
```

The command to get results for your `pyyaml` query consists of command above and simple `grep`:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} ${Version}\t${Homepage}\t${source:Package}\n' "*" | grep -i pyyaml
```

The result on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS will be as follows:

```
$ dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} ${Version}\t${Homepage}\t${source:Package}\n' "*" | grep -i pyyaml
libyaml-0-2:amd64 0.1.6-3   http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML  libyaml
python-yaml 3.11-3build1    http://pyyaml.org/  pyyaml
python3-yaml 3.11-3build1   http://pyyaml.org/  pyyaml
```

in the output above all `pyyaml` occurrences will be marked in *red color*, the `python3-yaml` exists in the output.

## Not installed packages

For not installed packages we can use other low-level handy command - `grep-dctrl` from `dctrl-tools` package (see [`man grep-available`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep-available.1.html) for details) to parse `/var/lib/dpkg/available`.

We will use the following syntax:

```
grep-available --field=Homepage,Source --ignore-case YAML
```

also we can shorten the output by showing only package names (adding `--show-field=Package`):

```
grep-available --field=Homepage,Source --show-field=Package --ignore-case YAML /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

and we will get:

```
Package: libyaml-tiny-perl
Package: libyaml-0-2
Package: libyaml-0-2
Package: python3-yaml
```

We can get even more results by using `grep-aptavail` (see [`man grep-aptavail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep-aptavail.1.html)):

```
grep-aptavail --field=Homepage,Source --show-field=Package --ignore-case YAML
```

as it returns:

```
Package: golang-yaml.v2-dev
Package: libyaml-0-2
Package: libyaml-0-2-dbg
Package: libyaml-dev
Package: libyaml-doc
Package: libyaml-libyaml-perl
Package: libyaml-perl
Package: libyaml-tiny-perl
Package: python-yaml
Package: python-yaml-dbg
Package: python3-yaml
Package: python3-yaml-dbg
Package: libyaml-0-2
Package: libyaml-0-2-dbg
Package: libyaml-dev
Package: libyaml-libyaml-perl
Package: python-yaml
Package: python-yaml-dbg
Package: python3-yaml
Package: python3-yaml-dbg
Package: erlang-p1-yaml
Package: golang-github-ghodss-yaml-dev
Package: golang-goyaml-dev
Package: hiera-eyaml
...
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to list only installed packages: on my desktop Ubuntu I get same result as you, and on my Docker Ubuntu I get nothing (because pyyaml is not installed there). I will clarify my question, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Answer updated. See above.